# Can't connect to SQL Server database inside docker in travis

Tags: sql-server, docker, travis-ci

I have trouble connecting to a SQL Server database inside a docker container in travis.

Everything is working fine on my machine the error only occurs inside travis, can't figure out why.

Dockerfile:

```
from microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest

ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y

ENV MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Passw0rd

COPY hermes.bak /var/opt/mssql/backup/hermes.bak

CMD ["/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr"]
```

.travis.yml:

```
dist: trusty

services:
  - docker

before_install:
  - docker build -t hermes-db .
  - docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:1430:1433 --name hermes-db hermes-db
  - docker exec hermes-db /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'Passw0rd' -Q "RESTORE DATABASE [lbc_refs] FROM DISK = N'/var/opt/mssql/backup/hermes.bak' WITH MOVE 'lbc_refs' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/lbc_refs_data.mdf', MOVE 'lbc_refs_log' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/lbc_refs_log.ldf'"

script:
  - docker ps | grep -q hermes-db
```

Ending up with:

```
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2AF9.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..
```

When I run netstat -tulpn :

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:11211           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:1430          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:11211           0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 172.18.0.1:123          0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 172.17.0.5:123          0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123           0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp6       0      0 :::123                  :::*                                -
```

Comment: I wonder - is it possible that a file used to `docker build` the `hermes-db` image is in `.gitignore`?

Comment: no, gitignore is empty, in like 20 build, 2 worked and 18 failed with this error and when i rebuild the one who worked they failed.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same problem on multi tenants application using SQL Server on Travis CI.

Here is the final build: https://travis-ci.org/github/ron190/jsql-injection/builds/663658271

After a lot of try and errors I managed to stabilize connection on port 1433 following these rules:

- Use image `2019-GDR1-ubuntu-16.04` instead of `2017-latest`
- `EXPOSE 1434 1433` in Dockerfile, `1434` for `sqlcmd`, `1433` for Hibernate on C3P0
- Add `sleep 10s` before testing first connection with `sqlcmd`
- Use password that complies with sql server password policy

Some details about my debugging on [travis-ci.community](https://travis-ci.community/t/c3p0-failed-to-connect-to-sql-server-on-docker/7591?u=ron190).